# Add ImageView on top of TextView (ConstraintLayout)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I didn't found any way to put an ImageView on top of TextView(s) with **ConstraintLayout**. It should look like on the screenshot below but if I run my app the imageview disappears.

[image]

**Edit:**

Adding `android:translationZ="2dp"` to ImageView doesn't solve the issue.
However, here is my whole XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTableWhite"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:textColor="@color/colorTableBlack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTableWhite"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1"
        tools:textColor="@color/colorTableBlack" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTableRed"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line2"
        tools:textColor="@color/colorTableWhite" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:translationZ="2dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.426"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2" ,  check position of space2.

Comment: Can you post more of the xml please?

Comment: @Aaron yes, I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solution for this issue:

1. Your minSdk=24 so no need to use srcCompat. Try to change this:

> app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_warning"

to this:

> android:background="@drawable/ic_warning"

2. If you prefer to use app:srcCompat, then you should make a little modification to your getView method in TemplateRow.class. Below, modified version of getView() method:

   ```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   DisplayTemplate displayTemplate = getItem(position);
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

   final View result;

   if (convertView == null) {

       viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template, parent, false);
       viewHolder.line1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.line1);
       viewHolder.line2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.line2);
       viewHolder.line3 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.line3);
       viewHolder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
       viewHolder.description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
       viewHolder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

       result = convertView;

       convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
   } else {
       viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       result = convertView;
   }

   Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
   result.startAnimation(animation);
   lastPosition = position;


   viewHolder.title.setText(displayTemplate.getTitle());
   viewHolder.description.setText(displayTemplate.getDescription());

   Drawable drawable = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_warning, null);
   viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

   showModel(viewHolder.line1,displayTemplate.getLines().get(0));
   showModel(viewHolder.line2,displayTemplate.getLines().get(1));
   showModel(viewHolder.line3,displayTemplate.getLines().get(2));
   // Return the completed view to render on screen
   return convertView;}
   ```

Comment: My min API level is 24. Unfortunately both didn't work for me. I added the complete xml now

Comment: I tried your xml just changed colors, It is working with or without elevation. CompileSDK:28 and minSDK:24 Got a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/V7Nja5u Maybe there is something  in your code that makes your view invisible or changes its position.

Comment: I don't understand this. I checked it and I never did anything with the ImageView in code. The only thing I do is, to put it in a list. If you want to, you can take a look here: https://github.com/Philipp97714/LenaControl

Comment: Ok. I'm looking now

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `app:srcCompat`, so either change `ImageView` to `AppCompatImageView` in your XML layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="top"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```

Or change `app:srcCompat` to `android:src`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="top"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />
```

Comment: Good solutions @Aaron. Simpler and better than mine.